# How to export a function of a regular MFC DLL that is statically linked to MFC to use with a non MFC Win32 Console App in C++

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, dllimport, dllexport

I am very new in C++ world and this kind of task.
I am having a hard time to resolve this issue.
Any help is kindly appreciated!

I have created a regular MFC DLL that is statically linked to MFC. (This is the first time i ever created a MFC project)

### MFC DLL Header File Content

```
// Serial.h

#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'pch.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols

class SerialApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    SerialApp();
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SerialApp::Init();

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

### MFC DLL Definition File Content

```
// Serial.cpp

#pragma once
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "Serial.h"
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(SerialApp, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

SerialApp::SerialApp()
{
}

SerialApp theApp;

BOOL SerialApp::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SerialApp::Init()
    {
        AfxDebugBreak();
        std::cout << "Succeded";
    }
}
```

### Win32 Console Application Content

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{   
    //Load the DLL
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\C++ PROJECTS\\serial\\Debug\\Serial.dll");

    //Create the function
    typedef void(*Init_t)(void);
    Init_t Serial = (Init_t)GetProcAddress(lib, "Init");
    std::cout << GetLastError(); // This output's 127

    if (!Serial) {
        //ERROR.  Handle it.
    }

    __declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Init(void);
    //Init(); //LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Init(void)"

    std::getchar();
}
```

***When i use this approach:***

```
 __declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Init(void);
 Init();
```

> `//I am getting the linker error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Init(void)"`

***When i use this approach:***

```
typedef void(*Init_t)(void);

Init_t Serial = (Init_t)GetProcAddress(lib, "Init");
std::cout << GetLastError();
```

> `//I am getting error code 127 from the GetLastError() function. (The specified procedure could not be found)`

***When i use this approach:***

```
#include "Serial.h"

int main()
{   
    SerialApp pSerial;
    pSerial.Init();
    std::getchar();
}
```

> `//Serial.h forces me to include 'pch.h' before itself. if i include 'pch.h' into Win32 Console App before Serial.h It end's up with about 1000's of errors.`

**For Win32 Console Application Project:**

```
1. C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories is set to: D:\C++ PROJECTS\serial\Serial

2. Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies is set to : Serial.lib

3. Both Serial.lib and Serial.dll are included in the project and in the Debug folder.

4. Both MFC Dll Project and Win32 Console Projects are compiled in Debug x86 mode.
```

### Questions

> 1. **What i am doing wrong?**
> 2. **Is this even possible?**

**Thank you!**

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SerialApp::Init()` Is that a typo? The function that you try to `__declspec(dllimport)` is a free function, not a member of `SerialApp`.

Comment: For me none of them is a typo:) But it might be a typo. Can you please explain what i am doing wrong? How can i make the function a member of the class? Is the header declaration not enough to make it a member of the class?

`class SerialApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    SerialApp();
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SerialApp::Init();
`

Thank you!

Comment: It's really simple, in `main()` you declare a function named `Init()`, for which you did not provide an implementation (definition), so the linker fails. The member function `Init()` is a different function. It can be invoked through a class instance (eg `pSerialApp->Init()`), or using the class name (ie `SerialApp::Init()`) if it was a static member function). `Init()` will generate code and try to link to function named `Init()`, that it not member of any class. It's the same as `::Init()` (which is often used to tell the compiler to call a function in the global namespace rather the class).

Comment: Thank you Constantine! How can i create a class instance of Serial.dll inside the Win32 Console Application? Being honest, i didn't understand what you mean. Can you please provide me an example?

By doing `__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Init(void);` inside the main() function, I thought and hoped that the compiler can understand that i want to use the Init() method inside the Serial.lib and Serial.dll that i provide. > What is the problem with this part? `typedef void(*Init_t)(void);     Init_t Serial = (Init_t)GetProcAddress(lib, "Init");`

Comment: To be more specific. How can i do (C#) `[DllImport("Serial.dll")] public static extern void Init();` in C++? The "DllImport" for this DLL is also not working in C# by the way(`Unable to find an entry point named 'Init' in DLL 'Serial.dll'.`). It is obvious that i am doing something or everything wrong in the DLL and the application. Thank you!

Comment: @swartkatt You cannot import a member function like `SerialApp::Init` to a non-MFC app, because that app does not know about the `SerialApp` class, and cannot know about it since `SerialApp` is derived from `CWinApp` which is an MFC class, while your app is non-MFC. If you want to export a free function from the DLL, then make it `__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Init(void);` outside the `SerialApp` class, or any class for that matter. As for C#, which you only brought into the picture in the last comment, you cannot directly import any C++ classes or member functions, anyway.

Comment: @dxiv You are my man! Thank you very much for your help. I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is resolved by **@dxiv**'s comment:

> You cannot import a member function like `SerialApp::Init` to a non-MFC app,
> because that app does not know about the `SerialApp` class, and cannot
> know about it since `SerialApp` is derived from `CWinApp` which is an MFC
> class, while your app is non-MFC. If you want to export a free
> function from the DLL, then make it `__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Init(void);` outside the `SerialApp` class, or any class for that matter.

**1.** I removed the declaration `__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SerialApp::Init();` from the header file.

> **2.** Rewrite the definition of Init() in the ***Serial.cpp*** file as:

```
extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Init()
    {
        std::cout << "Succeded";
    }
}
```

> **3.** I call the function in Win32 Console App as:

```
int main()
{
    //Load the DLL
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\C++ PROJECTS\\serial\\Debug\\Serial.dll");

    //Create the function
    typedef void(*Init_t)(void); // <- You can name Init_t whatever you want.
    Init_t Serial = (Init_t)GetProcAddress(lib, "Init");

    if (!Serial) {
        std::cout << GetLastError();
        return 1;
    }

    Serial();   //<- Init() Function Call from Serial.dll
    
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**And all worked great!**

**Thank you everyone, who make time to read and answer my Question!**

Comment: +1 for following up with an answer. Just as a caution, leaving hardcoded paths like `D:\C++ PROJECTS\...` in the code will bite you back later if this is anything more than a one-time exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will keep your recommendation in mind!